# Azure DevOps Organisation - How do we buy more build minutes on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With new Azure DevOps UI, I dont see the option to upgrade to next tier so we can have more than 240 minutes build time.

Comment: btw: the limit was increased from 240 to 1800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the dashboard of your DevOps Account -> Organization Settings -> Retention and parallel jobs -> "Purchase parallel jobs" under 'Microsoft Hosted'